# OpenCV: where can I find CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE constants?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I have tried to build the sample program from OpenCV documentation, but i have encountered a problem:

> error: ‘CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE’ was not declared in this scope

Source of program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
Mat image;
image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

 if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
{
  printf( "No image data \n" );
  return -1;
}

 namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
 imshow( "Display Image", image );

 waitKey(0);

 return 0;  
}
```

I think that `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` constants have been contained in a certain header file, but I can't find the necessary header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since all the windowing stuff is in the highgui module, you'll need

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

also, you'll need to *link* against the opencv_highgui library later

Comment: This didn't work for me, however #include <opencv/highgui.h> did. Why is this?

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC - you're using the obsolete c-api (don't do that!), above answer was for 2.4.9

Comment: Then what should I use? Including <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> does nothing, even though CMake says it's linking the executable against opencv_highgui (message("${OpenCV_LIBS}") --> [...];opencv_highgui;[...] )     , everything else works otherwise so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Never mind, just found out that I was reading the docs all wrong. You were right about using the c-api though.

Answer (score 13):

`CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` actually really *is* found in `highgui.h`, BUT, as @berak pointed out in the comments, *that*'s part of the obsolete c-api. You should instead do one of two things:

- Use `WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` instead, which is part of the C++ API. You don't need to change anything else to make this work, not even #include anything that isn't already #included in the example.
- Use `namedWindow( "Display Image" )` instead, since namedWindow uses `WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` by default and so you don't even have to include it as an argument.

Tested for OpenCV 3.0.0

Comment: Yeah, the version is important in this kind of opensource thing. Whenever a recently popular library gets updated, all the tutorials and troubleshooting stay out of date and no one realizes until after hours of fruitless investigating.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that in OpenCV 3.1 you need to use `cv::WindowFlags::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` which is located in `<opencv2/highgui.hpp>`.

Answer (score 4):

For opencv 4, it is defined in `<opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>`

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue and use

> WINDOW_AUTOSIZE instead of

> CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE

Answer (score 1):

It has been change in version 4. 
You can use directly WIDOW_AUTOSIZE if have defined using namespace cv as in your example.
Also, do not forget to add the correct dependencies for opencv

Answer (score -2):

You will find it in `highgui.h`.